# Clicking on Logo and Clicking on Questions does different things but the screen looks the same?

Tags: discussion, navigation

This really confused me when I first started coming here a few days ago.

Why is the layout the same between clicking on the logo and clicking on "Questions" in the main navigation?

Shouldn't there be a difference to distinguish the 2? They seemed like the same page but the only difference is the submenus.

Also the primary navigation seems to be changing a ton as well. Is there a better way of bringing up ever-changing options within context?

What it's doing now is very disorienting.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a Senior Product Designer here at Stack Exchange. I'll try and address some of your questions:

> Why is the layout the same between clicking on the logo and clicking on "Questions" in the main navigation?

Well they are laid out differently, albeit not *very* differently. Notice the two screenshots below. The top one is if you click on the UX logo and the bottom is if you click on "Questions."

[image: UX "Homepage"]
[image: UX Questions]

You'll notice a few changes:

- The page titles are different: Top Questions becomes All Questions.
- The "Questions" link is lightened and has an up-arrow point at it in the bottom image.
- The filter menus change.

If you're asking why we even have the two pages, think of Top Questions as a homepage. [**Grace Note** gives a quick run-down on the differences between the two pages on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50988/difference-between-active-top-questions-and-active-questions).

> Also the primary navigation seems to be changing a ton as well. Is there a better way of bringing up ever-changing options within context?

The only menuing that changes are the filter "tabs"/lines.

> What it's doing now is very disorienting.

I don't disagree. I find it disorienting at times because the layouts *are* so similar. We can always look at making it a clearer. Thanks for the feedback!